How to get an entry by a specific field value
I have some entries that have a field group containing two fields, ID and description.  I want to know how I can retrieve the description based on the ID. The IDs are unique.

A simple example would be to use the search: parameter to get the ID:
{exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" search:your_id_field="abc123"}
  {your_description_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}


That parameter should have an additional = sign to be an exact match:
search:your_id_field="=abc123"
and it's worth mentioning that it can be very slow searching on a lot of entries so be aware of that if you need to scale it large.

Absolutely that if you want exact matching.

Should be simple enough there are a few ways this can be done.
First is using entry id
{exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" entry_id="1"}
  {description}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Second is using an if statement
    {exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel"}
{if entry_id="1"}
  {description}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Third is if you are on the detail page for the one you want to search it should select the correct item.
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="yourchannel" 
    limit="1" 
    }{description}{/exp:channel:entries}

